# Awarding prizes based on percentages with ties in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write some sql to assign a value based on a position and each position gets a certain percentage of a total figure variable. There may be positional ties. if there are ties, for example there is a 3 way tie for 4th position, all 3 entries receive an equal amount of the percentage summed up for 3rd, 4th, and 5th position. So I need to calculate the value for each position in those ties and then split evenly. Then the next position will get 6th place and repeat until the last position has been reached.

I already have a ranking function, I just need to sort out the value assignments. There is a set amount for the total distribution, and I have a table storing all of the values for each of the positions. How would I implement this with pro grammatically, preferable in a combination of php and mysql Many thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Can you abstract away all the stuff about "prizes" and "payouts"? We have no idea what that means in your application, and it probably doesn't matter to the problem at hand.

Comment: Does it really have to be in SQL? This seems quite complex for SQL but fairly easy to program in just about any language.

Comment: Many thanks so far, I have reworded it a bit, hopefully for the better. I also have changed up the language requirement to a preference but not a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't do windowing functions so this gets hairy.

```
CREATE TABLE scores (score real);
CREATE TABLE prizes (prize real); /* in any order but assumed distinct, minor changes otherwise */

CREATE VIEW ranked_scores AS
SELECT s.score, 
    1+COUNT(s2.score > s.score) AS best_place, 
    -1+COUNT(s2.score=s.score) AS n_tied_with
FROM score s JOIN score s2 ON s2.score>=s.score;

/* if prizes can be the same we need something more like the view above */
CREATE VIEW ranked_prizes AS
SELECT p.prize, COUNT(p2.prize) AS prize_rank
FROM prize p JOIN prize p2 ON p.prize<=p2.prize;

/* there are more efficient ways of getting those ranks except I don't know
 * MySQL syntax for getting a pseudo-table 1..n, and windowing functions
 * are not available IFAIK.*/

SELECT score, avg(prize) FROM ranked_scores JOIN ranked_prizes
ON prize_rank between best_place and best_place+n_tied_with;
```